# How would I fix no wifi issue?

Tags: 12.04, wireless

I run Ubuntu 12.04 on a netbook and had to reinstall recently. I went to update because it said I needed 278 updates. The update got interrupted and now my Wifi doesn't want to connect.

Comment: How does you WiFi not want to connect? Does it continuously ask you for the password? Do you see wireless networks? Does Ubuntu not detect the wireless card?

Comment: its not picking it up at all.Normally illsee my Wifi router, but no router.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe **rfkill** blocked your wifi.

Run this in Terminal:

```
sudo rfkill unblock wifi
```

With rfkill list you can check if your wifi is unblocked. After that you should be fine.